# How to close old activity before opening next?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am building an Android app and are using the Parse SDK for Android.
Currently I am subscribing to channels with this in my main activity:

```
PushService.subscribe(this, "User_1_channel", MainActivity.class")
```

This works fine except for one thing. It opens up MainActivity and it gets put upon the other MainActivity in the stack which is very bad. I really want to remove the old activity before the new launches. I know I can do it with this but I have no idea where to put it since the Parse SDK handles everything.

```
launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

People say an alternative is to use a Custom broadcastreceiver. Problem with that approach is I have no idea how to subscribe to a channel without specifying an activity as the third parameter.

Comment: Try adding `android:noHistory="true"` to Activity A in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the activity as `SingleTask` in your configuration file, it will indicate only that one activity will be used the Task.

```
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
```